What was I thinking when I made this grid?
Inspired by this post and a true story :)

I was going through some old PDF documents on my computer, and I found one that I'd forgotten about. Among the contents was this grid:

Here's a CSV version:
X,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
2,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
3,3,2,1,4,2,6,3,8,4,10
4,4,3,4,1,6,7,2,9,10,3
5,5,4,2,6,1,8,4,10,2,12
6,6,5,6,7,8,1,10,11,12,13
7,7,6,3,2,7,8,1,10,11,12,13
8,8,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,14,15
9,9,8,4,10,2,12,6,14,1,16
10,10,9,10,3,12,13,4,15,16,1

What was I doing when I created this grid? What does it represent?
Some notes:

The top row and leftmost column represent a sort of coordinate pair, or a pair of inputs; they are not part of the actual data within the grid (same with the top-left X)
The solution has nothing to do with the image, just the numbers and values themselves.
This grid itself is infinite, the 10x10 size is just a section of it.
While this post does contain the knowledge tag, it's not actually necessary to solve the puzzle, but it can help.

Hints will be added if necessary. Enjoy!

You were inspired to tidy only your computer, not the entire house? :)

@Lezzup Who knows, maybe that'll become a new puzzle ;)

When you created this grid, you were

waiting for the famous bouncing DVD logo to hit a corner, as seen on The Office.

The entry in row x and column y represents

the number of bounces it takes the logo to start in one corner and end in another if the screen has x times the width and y times the height of the logo.

To compute this value,

let the sizes of the logo and screen be $1\times1$ and $x\times y$. Then the horizontal and vertical distances the logo travels are $x-1$ and $y-1$. The logo reaches another corner after traveling a total horizontal/vertical distance equal to the least common multiple of $x-1$ and $y-1$, and it bounces each time it travels $x-1$ units horizontally or $y-1$ units vertically.

This gives the formula for

the total number of bounces as $$\frac{\mathrm{lcm}(x-1,y-1)}{x-1}+\frac{\mathrm{lcm}(x-1,y-1)}{y-1}-1,$$ where we subtract 1 to avoid double-counting the last bounce. Because $$\mathrm{lcm}(x-1,y-1)=\frac{(x-1)(y-1)}{\gcd{(x-1,y-1)}},$$ we can also write this as $$\frac{x+y-2}{\gcd{(x-1,y-1)}}-1.$$


Ahhh, that explains all of the weird offsets I noticed.

I'm extremely impressed, congratulations! Out of curiosity, what led you to this conclusion?

@BlueHerring Observing the gcd pattern and coming up with a way to explain the offset. This kind of problem is also something I've daydreamed about before while staring at a grid of tiles :-)

Slightly interesting to note that this will always eventually succeed when starting from a corner, but it would be possible to never succeed when starting from elsewhere.

I'd say that, at least in my interpretation,

 the top and left rows should not be there, and the axes should be shifted over.

This is because the grid shows

 Euclid's Orchard, an infinite grid of infinitely thin trees, with an observer standing at one of the grid points.





 Each number labels which 'diagonal' the visible tree in that direction is on (with diagonals in this coordinate system numbered as $x+y-1$). In other words, visible trees are labelled with their diagonal; blocked trees inherit their labels from visible trees.

Another way to see this is that

 in the new coordinate system I'm using, where both axes are shifted over by 1:


 
 to get the number in a cell, interpret $x/y$ as a fraction - simplifying fully to get $n/d$ - and then the number in that cell is $n+d-1$.

(I'm not sure of a 'clean' way to get rid of the offset in that latter explanation, or of a more natural way to account for the clearly-aberrant first row and column. But I do believe this idea to be along the lines of what you were thinking.)

Not exactly, but it does involve similar mathematics / geometry. Very interesting relationship that I never noticed :)
